Eliminating Parameter and Dividing by a Variable in the Process
Suppose you are given the following two equations and asked to eliminate the parameter:
$$
y = 2\sin(2\theta)
$$
$$
x = \cos(\theta)
$$
To eliminate the parameter, I first made use of the double-angle identity:
$$
y = 4\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) 
$$
$$
y = 4x\sin(\theta)
$$
$$
\frac{y}{4x} = \sin(\theta)
$$
Now, I can simply make use of the Pythagorean Identity:
$$
\left(\frac{y}{4x}\right)^2 + x^2 = 1
$$
$$
\left(\frac{y}{4x}\right)^2 = 1 - x^2
$$
$$
\frac{y^2}{16x^2} = 1 - x^2
$$
$$
y^2 = 16x^2 - 16x^4
$$
But this answer raises an issue. Namely, during the first phase of simplification, I divided by $4x$, which implies that I assumed x is non-zero. How does this step affect my final answer? Should I denote that x must be non-zero?
There are other ways to arrive at the same answer without dividing by $x$. As such, by denoting that x cannot be non-zero, I now realize that my answer would no longer be equivalent to those answers.
I apologize if this is an elementary question.

You would conclude: either $x\ne0$ and $y^2 = 16x^2 - 16x^4$, or $x=y=0$, and these 2 cases are unified in: just $y^2 = 16x^2 - 16x^4$.

Here is one alternative way to proceed: from $y = 4x\sin(\theta)$ you get $y^2 = 16x^2\sin^2(\theta)$, while from $x = \cos(\theta)$ you find $x^2 = \cos^2(\theta) \implies 16x^4 = 16 x^2 \cos^2(\theta)$.
Thus $y^2 + 16x^4 = 16x^2\sin^2(\theta)  + 16 x^2 \cos^2(\theta) = 16 x^2 \implies y^2  = 16 x^2 - 16x^4$ without dividing by $x$.
Note that you might also claim that your approach works for $x\neq0$, but looking at the parametric equation you may say that the last equation holds for $x=0$ as well.

So, in my case, should I still indicate that x should be non-zero? How would you formally show that the last equation holds for x = 0?

Well, whenever you divide by "something", you must outline that "something" is not zero. As for your second question, substitute $x=0$ in $x=\cos(\theta)$ and solve for $\theta$. What can you say about $y$?

I see. You can show that x = 0 implies that y = 0. Therefore, the equation above holds when x = 0 since both sides will be zero.

Exactly. See the comment by Anne Bauval.
